# C mqueue doesn't send or receive the entire message

Tags: c, message-queue, mqueue

I tried to implement a simple C program using message queues, however the queue doesn't send or receive messages that are longer than 8 characters. I tried to set up all parameters correctly, but I must be missing something.

Below is the code and output.

code:

```
int main()
{
    mqd_t mq = mq_open("/mq", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);
    if (mq == -1) exit(1); 

    char* mes = "adventure";
    int n = mq_send(mq, mes, sizeof(mes), 0);
    char* mes2 = "eightcharacters";
    n = mq_send(mq, mes2, sizeof(mes2), 0);
    if (n == -1) exit(1);

    struct mq_attr attr;
    int buflen;  
    char *buf;

    mq_getattr(mq, &attr);
    buflen = attr.mq_msgsize;
    buf = (char *) malloc(buflen);

    printf("buflen: %d\n", buflen);

    n = mq_receive(mq, (char *) buf, buflen, NULL);
    if (n == -1) { exit(1); }

    printf("%s\n",buf);

    n = mq_receive(mq, (char *) buf, buflen, NULL);
    if (n == -1) { exit(1); }

    printf("%s\n",buf);

    free(buf);
    mq_close(mq);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
buflen: 8192
adventur
eightcha
```

Comment: Learn the difference between `sizeof` and `strlen`. Then learn about how strings are *terminated*.

Comment: regarding this line: `int n = mq_send(mq, mes, sizeof(mes), 0);` the expression: `sizeof(mes)`  is getting the sizeof the pointer, not the length of the message contents.   suggest: `int n = mq_send(mq, mes, strlen(mes), 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof` will give you the size of the pointer (you seems to be on a 64bits architecture, so pointers are 8 bytes long).

To correct your code:

- use `strlen` function instead of `sizeof` (in that case, you must take care of final `\0`)

**or**

- replace your string declaration:

`char mes2[] = "eightcharacters";`

Answer (score 1):

Given the code

```
char* mes = "adventure";
int n = mq_send(mq, mes, sizeof(mes), 0);
```

`sizeof(mes)` is the size of the **pointer** `mes`, not the length of the string it points to.